# php javascript cookies

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I am trying to use Cookies to send information from php to javascript.
but while the coockie saved fine on $_COOKIE, 
from javascript i can only see:

```
PHPSESSID=e5289f50a9971fd0e1c954904056290e
```

any ideas about whats I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If the cookie you are setting is HTTP only cookie then it wont be accessible from JavaScript code. Check out HTTP Cookie on google

Answer (score -1):

Trying to pass information from php to javascript will make things very complex if not impossible. Why don't you use PHP only for handling cookies if you have server side coding involved? And JavaScript only if you are concerned about client side only? 
There are plenty of tutorials available to handle cookies in JavaScript as well as in PHP. 
For javaScript you may refer [this wikipedia writeup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) or visit [w3resource JavaScript Cookies tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/cookies/introduction-cookies.php). For PHP visit PHP Cookies from PHP Manual or w3resource PHP cookies tutorial. Hope these help.

Comment: i need to interact with the user according to data on the server, so i must use both server-side and client-side languages